# SKU for each product on every page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I got the sku to to show in the cart for each item - Does anyone have the correct php code to get the sku under each product name on all pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook,

so code will be like

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_sku' ); function product_sku(){ global $product; echo '<div class="sku-product">' . $product->sku . '</div>'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title',  'custom_after_title' );
function custom_after_title() {

global $product;

if ( $product->get_sku() ) {
    echo $product->get_sku();
}

}